# Google cloud storage upload using generic signed url and curl

Tags: google-app-engine, curl

I am trying to put a file into a Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket from the command line. At a later stage this shall be used in a deployed script at the user end without any type of user-visible authentication.

So far I generate a signed url like this:

```
gsutil signurl -p notasecret -m PUT -d 1d myserviceaccount.p12 gs://mybucket/testfile
```

which will generate something like

https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket/testfile?GoogleAccessId=myserviceaccount@developer.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1430963040&Signature=gMf2h95bNmolizUGYrsQ%2F%2F%2FiHxW14I%2F0EOU3ZSFWtfCwNqSyok3iweQiuPxYXH4b26FeDSrmFOXB58%2B%2B%2BiAOJ%2B1gdLC9Y%2BkeUdbrjH0eGTW0NVsM1AWY2LsQ3dYf5Ho%2Bos1Fk26EsLJlD096Ku9aWqLW%2FpL%2FBSsUIfHijrFJPdI%3D

The next step (at the user end) would be `curl` uploading the file with a PUT request. Like so:

```
curl -X PUT --data-binary @testfile 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mybucket/testfile?GoogleAccessId=myserviceaccount@developer.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1430963040&Signature=gMf2h95bNmolizUGYrsQ%2F%2F%2FiHxW14I%2F0EOU3ZSFWtfCwNqSyok3iweQiuPxYXH4b26FeDSrmFOXB58%2B%2B%2BiAOJ%2B1gdLC9Y%2BkeUdbrjH0eGTW0NVsM1AWY2LsQ3dYf5Ho%2Bos1Fk26EsLJlD096Ku9aWqLW%2FpL%2FBSsUIfHijrFJPdI%3D'
```

I can get this to work with an existing file in the bucket and a GET request (for downloading), but it does not seem to work for uploading. `curl` throws the server's response with error messages like this at me:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
         Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>
<StringToSign>PUT

application/x-www-form-urlencoded
1430963040
/mybucket/testfile</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

And this makes sense to me, as obviously I am not just making a bare PUT request, but one for a particular file of a specific size, whereas the signature computed by 'gsutil signurl' would not know about these details at the time it is computed.

Somehow I was under the impression (e.g., based on the last usage case described in [`gsutil signurl` documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl) and also in the post [How to allow anonymous uploads to cloud storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158266/how-to-allow-anonymous-uploads-to-cloud-storage)) that it should be possible to generate a generic signed url for uploading purposes and then use it later. Am I just mistaken about this point or is there a way to fix the `curl` request?

Any thoughts about this are appreciated. However, I'd like this to work with "minimal tools", i.e., ideally shell and curl only, but no other programming languages.

**EDIT:**
Organising one's thoughts by formulating the exact problem is the first step towards the solution. I realise now that

```
curl -X PUT -T - [request-url] < testfile
```

does actually solve the immediate problem. However, this means multiple users would write to the same file if they use the same signed url. The documentation suggests you can omit the object name in the creation of the signed url, i.e., use

```
gsutil signurl -p notasecret -m PUT -d 1d myserviceaccount.p12 gs://mybucket/
```

This, supposedly, would allow anyone with the resulting signed url to put any object of any type into my bucket. Only I do not get this work, as I don't see how you can then tell GCS which object you are actually writing to.

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I am having the same problem, getting access denied.

Comment: Nothing to report here since those edits. Unfortunately.

Comment: i got the same problem

Comment: >  The documentation suggests you can omit the object name in the creation of the signed url

- Where do you see that? You have to specify the object name.

Comment: The last usage case under the [first doc link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl#usage) states "To construct a signed URL that allows anyone in possession of the URL to PUT to the specified bucket for one day, creating **any object** of Content-Type image/jpg [...]". This gives me the impression the object does not have to be determined at signed url creation time. However, in the following example code they DO state an object (or placeholder for one).

Comment: Maybe this helps. I have an appengine Python script which uses a form post to send a file to GCS. The post request is signed. Appengine makes creating a post HTML form very easy, without the need for a local p12 key. More here: https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-upload

Comment: i got the same problem

Answer (score 5):

This was driving me mad too. Turns out it was the `binary-file` part of the curl command. Try this instead:

```
curl -X PUT --upload-file me.jpeg $SIGNED_URL
```

Answer (score 1):

If the resource does not specify a single object, you can do so on an individual basis by adding a URL param to the request with the name of the object. For example:

`curl -X PUT -T - [request-url]?name=[object-name] < testfile`

This surely works with `storage/v1`, although I have not tried myself with a signed URL yet.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. The storage/v1 approach uses different URLs and the POST method for inserting objects. `gsutil signurl` on the other hand does not support the POST method (it uses PUT). Just replacing my PUT request URL above with `https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/mybucket/o?GoogleAccessId=...as_before...?name=myobject` does not seem to work for me, either.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar problem(403 forbidden).
It turned out that my json library, which I use it to marshal each response, would replace `&` by `\u0026` for security concern. So the url may be correct in the program but invalid in client side
So I guess that there might be some string encoding bug inside the `Signature` query string of your url since the signature string is harder to detect error in comparison with my `\u0026`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think it is a url encoding problem, as  the command `curl -X PUT -T - [request-url] < testfile` does work for me. The HTTP 403 response you got is a strong indicator that that something with the URL is not right and the wrong object or a nonexisting object is requested. Glad to hear you could work out the reason for this and fix it.